# How to select, add, limit or level select hierarchical taxonomy terms as field widget values?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

To sort and "tag" content hierarchically Drupal has/had the great ability to build hierarchical term trees like: car > toyota > combi, car > ford > lector, etc. which could be added to content in different ways.

There are 3 modules, I know of which provided field widgets for the ability to hierarchical select, add, limit or level select taxonomy terms as field values in Drupal 7 to add these terms of a certain level to content and with some limitations for Drupal 8. Hierarchical Select, Simple Hierarchical Select and Clientside Simple Hierarchical Select.

Looking at the project pages of each module, it seems, the user has been left allone on a dead end when it comes to complex hierarchical term usage in post Drupal 7 days. HS development has been stopped. SHS further development has been stopped too, and CSHS has too many bugs and limitations (I am not able to add new terms on any level in a field widget form).

How do users use complex hierarchical term lists for field form values nowadays? Does the concept of terms stopped gaining enough interest to call out for contrib solutions or do I do not see the options, I knew I was able to do such things back in the days with Hirarchical Select? Are there work arounds or completely different approaches how to reach the same goals without hierarchical terms?

Comment: Oh! Funny ... That question seems to be "zeitgeist" :-) >> https://twitter.com/maroqqo/status/1039198721156755461